# Sort data in react table - not alphabitacelly, but specific order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html-table

I am first time playing with the React and I would like to sort data by column "Status", but not alphabetically, but with the specific order, let's say B, A, C and vice versa.

I have data as:

```
export interface Delivery {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  amount: number;
  status: string;
  eta?: number;
}

export const getDeliveries = (): Promise<Delivery[]> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const data = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Delivery 1",
          amount: 3,
          status: "A",
          eta: 15
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Delivery 2",
          amount: 5,
          status: "C"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Delivery 3",
          amount: 3,
          status: "A",
          eta: 10
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Delivery 4",
          amount: 4,
          status: "B"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Delivery 5",
          amount: 3,
          status: "A",
          eta: 25
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "Delivery 6",
          amount: 3,
          status: "C",
          eta: 5
        }
      ];

      resolve(data);
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

Thanks for any help or tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort your data using the built-in Array.sort with a custom comparator.

1. Define the order by which the status field should be sorted.
2. Sort the data array using a custom comparator function, which compares the two data points by their status' "value" in the status order array you defined earlier.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Delivery 1",
    amount: 3,
    status: "A",
    eta: 15
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Delivery 2",
    amount: 5,
    status: "C"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Delivery 3",
    amount: 3,
    status: "A",
    eta: 10
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Delivery 4",
    amount: 4,
    status: "B"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Delivery 5",
    amount: 3,
    status: "A",
    eta: 25
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Delivery 6",
    amount: 3,
    status: "C",
    eta: 5
  }
];
const statusOrder = ["B", "A", "C"];

data.sort((d1, d2) => statusOrder.indexOf(d1.status) - statusOrder.indexOf(d2.status));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: note `.sort` mutates the array so in order to mantain the immutability of the state you can't apply it directly to the state variable instead you must copy the array, mutate it and then update the state with the new array.

Comment: @AnsonMiu FYI Jaro is asking you (and me) to solve an [interview challenge](https://codesandbox.io/s/hcpreinterviewchallenge-19r54) for a [job application](https://www.heidelbergcement.com/en/software-engineer-front-end-react-fmd-%282870%29).  Don't do it.  Your answer here is a good answer to the question that is asked.  *"can you please try to adapt your tip to my working demo"* - it takes a lot of nerve to ask internet strangers to fill out your job application.